# Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<any[]>'

Tags: firebase, angular4, angular-datatables

Soy nuevo con **Angular**, es mi primer curso que tomo sobre ello y lo estoy tratando de complementar con **Firebase**, pero cuando trato de obtener los objetos que contiene mi nodo a un **AngularFireList** obtengo este error, mi código es el siguiente:

```
 my_notes: AngularFireList<any[]>;

 constructor(public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.getNotes()
      .subscribe(
        notas => {
          this.my_notes = notas;
        }
      );
  }

  getNotes(){
    return this.afDB.list('/notas').valueChanges();
  }
```

Y el error que obtengo es este:

> Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList'.
>   Property 'query' is missing in type '{}[]'.

Gracias por la ayuda.